# Can bing maps streetside be used standalone?

Tags: bing-maps

I am working on a project and looking for an alternative to google maps street view and am considering bing maps street side. I am wondering if streetside can be used standalone (without bing maps)? I found a JS example to disable the map but it is still possible to bring it up. I just want to use the street view.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - take a look at [StreetsideOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/v8-web-control/map-control-api/streetsideoptions-object) where various things on top of the Streetside view can be hidden. Here is a sample code snippet with everything turned off:

```
map.setOptions({ 
    streetsideOptions: { 
        overviewMapMode: Microsoft.Maps.OverviewMapMode.hidden,
        showCurrentAddress: false,
        showProblemReporting: false,
        showExitButton: false,
        disablePanoramaNavigation: true,
        showHeadingCompass: false,
        showZoomButtons: false 
    } 
});
```